# .py file not running properly in py.exe, works in eclipse

Tags: python, excel, database, pandas, pyodbc

Hi I have a simple python script that uses an odbc driver to connect to a database get a dataframe and store it/overwrite an excel file. When I run the script using eclipse, it works just fine. However, when I run it by right clicking the .py file and open with py.exe, the excel file is not being overwritten/saved.

Ultimately, I want other users to be able to install python and just double click a .py script to update an excel file. Does anyone know why it is not working with the right click method? They should both be using the same interpreter when I checked.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd



cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver (x64)};'
                       'DSN=MyDSN;'
                       'Server=ServerAddress;'
                       'Database=Stuff;')

t1 = "table1"


sql = ("select * " + "from " + t1)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyExcelFile.xlsx")
dframe = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
aggDf = dframe.groupby(['DEPARTMENT']).sum()
dframe.to_excel(writer,"RawSalesData", index = False)
aggDf.to_excel(writer, "SalesStats")

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

---

Below is the results of running the sys code suggested by Jacob in the comment. Seems like both methods match.

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
[
'C:\\Users\\persona\\PythonWorkSpace\\TestPython', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\libs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\pkgs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\conda-meta', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\envs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\etc', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\include', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Lib', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Library', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\man', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Menu', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Scripts', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\share', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\sip', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\tcl', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Tools', 
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'
]
^ right click method
--------------------

sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
[
'C:\\Users\\persona\\PythonWorkSpace\\TestPython', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\PythonWorkSpace\\TestPython', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\libs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\pkgs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\conda-meta', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\envs', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\etc', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\include', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Lib', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Library', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\man', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Menu', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Scripts', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\share', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\sip', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\tcl', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\anaconda3\\Tools', 
'C:\\Program Files\\eclipse', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Users\\persona\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a python file like this:

```
from sys import version_info, path
print(version_info)
print(path)
```

Then try opening with both methods you mentioned. The results should match, and if they don't then there is your issue. If they do match, you should add more logging/exception handling so we can see why this fails.